# Why do runners immediately stop after a run? Does opening your mouth more while running affect oxygen intake?

Tags: running, exercise-technique

Hello all. I've got two questions regarding the way runners run.

Firstly, what I've always thought is that stopping immediately after completing the run (1k / 2k / 3k / 5k) is bad and we should like carry on at a slow pace for some distance.

But why is it that the runners in [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v8atqt-o5-Y) stop immediately after they've completed the run? Isn't it bad for their bodies? (Once  my friend even told me that they would get "rectum pus" whatever that is.)

Secondly, what I've always thought is that we should open our mouth "bigger" to allow for more intake of oxygen during the run. What I've seen in [the same video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v8atqt-o5-Y) is that they do not do so. Does anyone know why is it so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You're right that it's very important to [cool down](http://www.24hrfitness.co.uk/fitness%20tips/cooling-down-after-exercise.html) after
   exercising. Cool down should consist of three phases: gentle
   exercise (to gradually lower the heart rate and prevent dizziness),
   stretching (to reduce muscle stiffness), and refueling. Here's
   [another useful article](http://pfitzinger.com/labreports/cooldown.shtml) on cooling down.

   In general, as xpda points out, a lot of runners neglect the cool
   down because they're so exhausted at the end of a race (I know I'm
   guilty of this from time to time). A cool down is designed to
   restore your body to pre-exercise conditions, but it still takes
   effort. Stretching can be somewhat painful if you've really
   worked your muscles.

   In the video you linked to, however, the runner was immediately
   swept into celebration following the race, so he didn't exactly have
   the opportunity to cool down.
2. According to [this article](http://daveelger.articlesbase.com/sports-and-fitness-articles/improve-your-running-with-proper-breathing-45455.html) - it's best to breathe through both
   the nose and the mouth while running. So perhaps it's unnecessary to
   open the mouth very wide if you're also breathing through your nose.

Answer (score 4):

1. In a race, you may not be *able* to jog for a while afterward, especially if you put everything into a sprint in at the end.
2. The size of the mouth is not normally the limiting factor for air intake, so you don't need to open it any wider. Incidentally, CO2 output is as important as oxygen intake.

Comment: could you elaborate on the point on CO2 output?

Comment: For each molecule of O2 you inhale, you have to exhale a molecule of CO2. Otherwise, you'll get too much CO2 in your system and your muscles will quit working, or at least slow down. This is automatic, though, because you always exhale after you inhale.

Comment: i mean.. do you mean to say there is something we can do to have *more CO2 output* ?

Comment: No. It's automatic. Here's an interesting site that shows how CO2 output increases with exercise:  http://www.sciencebuddies.org/science-fair-projects/project_ideas/Zoo_p013.shtml